# getting data from table to another table when selected

Tags: php, sql

this program works properly i just don't know how to make this additional function work...

dbconfig.php

```
<?php

  $db_host = "localhost";
  $db_name = "testproduct";
  $db_user = "root";
  $db_pass = "";

  try{

      $db_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_pass);
     $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   }
   catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
   }


    ?>
```

Product Management

Here in product management I will add the product information name,price,stock etc..

add_form.php

```
<?php
  require_once 'dbconfig.php';


   if($_POST)
   {
     $fname = $_POST['name'];
     $lname = $_POST['actualprice'];
     $contactnum = $_POST['sellprice'];
     $email = $_POST['Stock'];
     try{

           $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO   tblproduct(name,actualprice,sellprice,Stock)  VALUES(:pname,:pactualprice,:psellprice,:pStock)");
         $stmt->bindParam(":pname", $name);
         $stmt->bindParam(":pactualprice", $actualprice);
         $stmt->bindParam(":psellprice", $sellprice);
         $stmt->bindParam(":pStock", $Stock);
         if($stmt->execute())
         {
            echo "Successfully Added";
         }
         else{
            echo "Query Problem";
         }  
         }
        catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }
   }


  ?>


   <style type="text/css">
    #dis{
   display:none;
  }
  </style>




    <div id="dis">

    </div>


  <form method='post' id='emp-SaveForm' action="#">

  <table class='table table-bordered'>

     <tr>
         <td>Product Name</td>
         <td><input type='text' name='name' class='form-control' placeholder='EX : john doe' required /></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
         <td>Actual Price</td>
         <td><input type='text' name='actualprice' class='form-control' placeholder='EX : Web Design, App Design' required></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td>Sell Price</td>
         <td><input type='text' name='sellprice' class='form-control' placeholder='EX : 180000' required></td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
         <td>Stock</td>
         <td><input type='text' name='Stock' class='form-control' placeholder='EX : john doe' required /></td>
      </tr>


       <tr>
         <td colspan="2">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-save" id="btn-save">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Save this Record
         </button>  
         </td>
         </tr>

     </table>
     </form>
```

index.php

```
<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="example" class="table table-striped    table-hover table-responsive">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Actual Price</th>
      <th>Sell Price</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>edit</th>
      <th>delete</th>

      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php
       require_once 'dbconfig.php';

      $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblproduct ORDER BY id DESC");
      $stmt->execute();
      while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['actualprice']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['sellprice']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Stock']; ?></td>
        <td align="center">
        <a id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="edit-link" href="#" title="Edit">
        <img src="edit.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>
        <td align="center"><a id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="delete-link" href="#" title="Delete">
        <img src="delete.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
     }
     ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Sales Management

here is the problem in sales I will add a sales record which will require a product name. the product will be selected from the table of product management including the other information for that specific product(actual price,stock,selling price) that will be show on the index

add_form.php

```
<?php
 require_once 'dbconfig.php';


if($_POST)
{
    $pname = $_POST['pname']; 
    $gname = $_POST['gname'];
    $saledate = $_POST['saledate'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $actualprice = $_POST['actualprice'];
    $sellprice = $_POST['sellprice'];
    $profit = $_POST['profit'];
    $carryO = $_POST['carryO'];
    $sells = $_POST['sells'];
    $expense = $_POST['expense'];
    try{

        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tblsales(pname,gname,saledate,quantity,actualprice,sellprice,carryO,sells,expense,profit) 
                                 VALUES(:upname,:ugname,:usaledate,:uquantity,:uactualprice,:usellprice,:ucarryO,:usells,:uexpense,:uprofit)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":upname", $pname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ugname", $gname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":usaledate", $saledate);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uquantity", $quantity);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uactualprice", $actualprice);
        $stmt->bindParam(":usellprice", $sellprice);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ucarryO", $carryO);
        $stmt->bindParam(":usells", $sells);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uexpense", $expense);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uprofit", $profit);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo "Successfully Added";
        }
        else{
            echo "Query Problem";
        }   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

    ?>

 <div id="dis">

</div>


 <form method='post' id='emp-SaveForm' action="#">

<table class='table table-bordered'>

    <tr>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td><input type='text'name='pname' class='form-control'  required>  </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Guest Name</td>
        <td><input type='text'  name='gname' class='form-control'  required> </td>
    </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>Sale Date</td>
        <td><input type='date' name='saledate' class='form-control'  required></td>
      </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='quantity' class='form-control'  id="quantity"  required></td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Actual Price</td>

        <td>
        <input type='text'name ="actualprice" id="aaprice"   class='form-control'  required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Selling Price</td>
        <td>
        <input type='text' name='sellprice' class='form-control' type = "number"   id="ssprice"    required></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Carry Over</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='carryO' class='form-control'  required></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Sells</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='sells' class='form-control'  required></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Expense</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='expense' class='form-control'  required></td>
    </tr>



      <tr>
        <td>Profit</td>
        <td><input  name='profit' class='form-control' type = "number"  id="profit"  required></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-save" id="btn-save">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Save this Record
        </button>  
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

index.php

```
<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
   <th>Product Name</th> //selected from product management table
    <th>Sale Date</th>//(user input)
    <th>Quantity</th>//(user input)
    <th>Actual Price</th> //price of the selected product on the management table
    <th>Selling Price</th> //price of the selected product on the management table
    <th>Carry Over</th> //stock from the selected product on the management table 
    <th>Sells</th>//selling price of the selected product on the management table * quantity(user input)
    <th>Expense</th>
    <th>Profit</th>
    <th>edit</th>
    <th>delete</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

   if(isset($_POST['months'])){ $months = $_POST['months']; }else { $months='';}
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblsales WHERE MONTH(saledate) = '".$months."' ");  
   //this is for the sales management for the monthly view function    didn't include the my months select this post already long enough
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['pname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['saledate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['actualprice']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['sellprice']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['carryO']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['sells']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['expense']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['profit']; ?></td>
        <td align="center">
        <a id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="edit-link" href="#" title="Edit">
        <img src="edit.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>
        <td align="center"><a id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="delete-link" href="#" title="Delete">
        <img src="delete.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way by using ajax for this case.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "data.php",//file wich has query select to db table
            data: {id:theid},//describe your data here
            dataType: 'json',// type of data that will you get (JSON/HTML).
            type: 'POST',//sending type (POST/GET)
            success: function(data) {
               showTable();
            }
        });
```